# Is there a zsh command to output shell function code, like `type` in bash

Tags: bash, zsh, function

In `bash`, when I'd like to have a glimpse at what an already defined shell function does, I can:

```
$ type myFunctionName
```

For a variable `myFunctionName`, it provides me with the type of the variable (a function), but also print the source of this shell function on the terminal. Very handy.

When I do the same in `zsh`, it only gives me the its type, not its shell code.

Is there a way to ask `zsh` to print to source of a shell function given its name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both `zsh` and `bash` (and `ksh`) you can use `typeset -f myFunctionName` to get the function definition

```
% x()
function> {
function> echo x
function> }

% typeset -f x
x () {
        echo x
}
```

Comment: See also `which myFunctionName` in `zsh` (where `zsh` is builtin like in `tcsh`)

Comment: For completeness, in `yash`, you'd need `typeset -pf x`

Comment: I don't understand the `function>` notation . How do you make this prompt happen ?

Comment: The `function>` prompt automatically appeared for me when I began the function definition `x()` on the command line.  It's zsh's way of telling the user they're in the middle of defining a function.  It's the default on my (old) MacOS machine where I tested.

Comment: @StephenHarris thanks. I had forgotten I had already set an `alias x="exa"` ... That's the reason I had no such prompt when I hit enter try to do your example with `x ()`. That's excellent, I was always moving to `.sh` file when the one-liner was becoming a bit too complex but still easy. I'll use this now.